# Valid div identiier names ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am working on a new project for a client; they have supplied the site design which I need to move onto our content management system.

.NET doesn’t seem to like the  id's that are scattered throughout the theme.

Is there any reason why  -  throws ...is not a valid identifier?

Cheers for any responses.

**Examples**

```
<form id="login-form" runat="server">

<input type="text" name="username" runat="server" id="login-username" placeholder="Username" />
```

**Update**

Seems that changing - to _ fixes the issue. Answer below!

Matt

Comment: Can you give us some examples of lines throwing errors?

Comment: Not a problem... updating the Q now.

Comment: ID's with dashes in them cause problems for javascript and styling.  Be careful.

Comment: For sure, it's just how the whole site design was delivered to me; no classes for styling; all just using the div Id's.

The site looks & loads perfectly when I'm just viewing the standard html version, but asp.net seems to not like them.

Comment: Its worth checking out MSDN ASP.Net Web Server Control Identification,,, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ASP.NET, when you use `runat="SERVER"`, then the "ID" naming convention must follow the naming convention of the properties and fields. The "-" character is not allowed in field names.

Comment: Looks like I just figured that out a few mins back; cheers for the answer mate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the '-' (hyphen) sign between these ids. Sometimes one has to be cautious using such ids in Style Sheets. Remove them and see if that helps